# C fscanf adds an element to array and should not

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;

    input = fopen("algsort.in", "r");
    output = fopen("algsort.out", "w");

    int n = 0;
    fscanf(input, "%d", &n);        // reads n = 7

    int i;
    int a[6] = {1, -1, 0, 33, 6, 5};


    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {     // 8 is on purpuse
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);    // the output is [1 -1 0 33 6 5 7 $(Random location in memory)]
    }


    return 0;
}
```

fscanf appends an element at the end of the array. It is a problem, because it interferes with the sorting algorithm, leaving out an element bigger than n.
I know the limits of the for loop, the problem is, that the "n" element is still part of the array.
Question: Where did the 7 come from?

Comment: You are reading past the end of the array. Anything can happen.

Comment: You are indexing beyond the bounds of the array. Should be i < 7

Comment: Check the return value from `fscanf()` before using any scanned values.

Comment: A has only dimension 0..6, you address a[7]

Comment: @OldProgrammer It should be `i < size_of_array`, which is 6 in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `fscanf` appends an element at the end of the array.

No, it does not. Your array remains an array of six `int`s. The fact that you can go past the end of the array without a crash does not mean that your array somehow got an extra element - it means that undefined behavior did not result in a crash this time around.

> Where did the 7 come from?

From the location in memory that is `sizeof(int)` past the end of array `a`. Accessing this location through the array is undefined behavior, so any value could be returned. [A quick experiment shows](http://ideone.com/5HHrGu) that at least one compiler could lay out the memory inside your function in such a way that `n` is directly behind array `a`:

```
FILE *input = NULL;
FILE *output = NULL; 
int n = 0;
scanf("%d", &n); // reads n = 7
int a[6] = {1, -1, 0, 33, 6, 5};
printf("%p\n%p\n", (void*)&n, (void*)&a[6]);
```

This prints

```
0xbfabd5e4
0xbfabd5e4
```

which means that the address of `n` and the value of `a+6` (which is what you get when you dereference one element past the end of the array) point to the same address. If your compiler does the same thing, you would see the same result. Even if this is the case, this behavior remains undefined.

Answer (score 2):

All your variables are on [stack](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)[[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)] and your stack memory probably looks like this ([how to view it in visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx)):

```
     address  value  variable name
-> 0000 002c  7      n
-> 0000 0018  5      a[6]
-> 0000 0014  6      a[5] 
-> 0000 0010  3      a[4]
-> 0000 000c  33     a[3]
-> 0000 0008  0      a[2]
-> 0000 0004  -1     a[1]
-> 0000 0000  1      a[0]
```

And you're just "*lucky*" that `a[7]` points to the same memory as `n`.

I just run modified example under Linux with GCC and I got this:

```
 var   addres   value
n      c6798c   6
a[7]   c6798c   6
a[6]   c67988   4195600
a[5]   c67984   5
a[4]   c67980   6
a[3]   c6797c   33
a[2]   c67978   0
a[1]   c67974   -1
a[0]   c67970   1
```

I guess this is due to memory alignment and 64b OS.

Comment: "And you're just lucky that `a[7]` points to the same memory as `n`" I would call that "unlucky" :-) With some luck, the program would crash instead of hiding undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight agreed, it was meant to be in quotes